# Mysql RLIKE / PREG_MATCH bug

Tags: mysql, regex, encoding, character-encoding, rlike

Cold someone could explain why this returns true:

```
SELECT BINARY 'â' RLIKE '[™]';
SELECT BINARY 'é' RLIKE '[©]';
```

What could be the fix ? Is it some misconfiguration on my part?

**UPDATE:**

found that using `(™|©)` instead of `[™©]` would work as a first workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html):

> **Warning**
>   The REGEXP and RLIKE operators work in byte-wise fashion, so they are
>   not multi-byte safe and may produce unexpected results with multi-byte
>   character sets.

Comment: I understand now that `[]` operator is used for one byte match on each entry, and the `(|)` can be used for groups of characters so the multi-byte problem doesn't affect it's output.